# If $m^n = n^m$, why does $m$ to be a factor of $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $m^n = n^m$ with $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n > m.$

Why does $m$ have to be a factor of $n$?

I think it's because of the prime factorization, but I can't prove it.

Comment: $m$ is a factor of $n$, when there exists an integer $k$ with $n = k \cdot m$. I get from $m^n = n^m \rightarrow n = m \cdot m^{n/m-1}$, so $m^{n/m-1}$ would be $k$, but how can I be sure, that $m^{n/m-1}$ is an integer without knowing that $m$ is a factor of $n$?

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I only see why $m$ has to be a factor of $n^m$.

Comment: @lhf I'll just quit. I'm completely blind. All comments removed.

Comment: This problem leads to a rare identity: $m^{\frac{1}{m}}=n^{\frac {1}{n}}$ iff $m=n\cdot k$ where $m,n,k\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Maybe someone can correct me, but the only option for this to happen is $n=4,m=2$

Comment: Yeah, that is correct... Also if I didn't know why m has to be a factor of n, I can proof that n=4 and m=2 is the only solution. I can give you the proof, if you want.

Comment: @Belgi, yes, seeing the graph it obvious that the only naturals number that can lead to this equality is the 1 or 2 because the function $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ have a max on $x=e$. And $1$ obviously cant sustain the equality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $v_p(x)$ be the exponent of a prime $p$ in the factorization of $x$.

Then $m^n = n^m$ implies $n v_p(m) = m v_p(n) $ for all $p$.

Since $n >m$, we get $m v_p(n) = n v_p(m) \ge m v_p(m)$ and so $v_p(n) \ge v_p(m)$ for all $p$.

This means that $m$ divides $n$.

Alternatively, write $n=m+t$ with $t>0$. Then $m^n = n^m$ implies $n^t=q^m$, for $q=n/m$. Thus, $q$ is a rational root of the monic polynomial equation $x^m-n^t=0$. By the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), $q$ must be an integer and so $m$ divides $n$.

Comment: One more question, why have to be the same primes in the prime factorizations?

Comment: @Rummelluff, $v_p(x)=0$ if $p$ does not divide $x$. So, you can consider *all* primes.

Comment: Ah, now I get it! Thank you, lhf! I'm just wondering, is this a trivial thing?

Comment: @Rummelluff, it's easy if you're used to divisibility arguments using prime exponents, but not trivial. The rational root theorem is a good tool to know.